# FastAPI - On templates.TemplateResponse gives error - "in url_path_for raise NoMatchFound() starlette.routing.NoMatchFound"

Tags: python, fastapi

I used the GitHub search to find a similar issue which said this is some problem with fastapi's url_for vs flask's url_for. But no solution was available.
I used a similar code in flask it is working, this means no problem with the frontend or API in flask.
I searched the FastAPI documentation, but it did not show much on this issue, it was just a tutorial for rendering template.

```
@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)

def homepage(data: str, request: Request):
    ws_url = urlparse(request.url.query)
    ws_url = 'http://' + request.url.hostname + ':' + os.environ.get('SOCKET_PORT', default='5001') + '/mask'
    user_id, callback_url, source_url = load_homepage(data)
    if source_url != '':
        source_url = 'http://dev-editor.com/download?sourceUrl='+quote_plus(source_url)
    return templates.TemplateResponse('homepage.html', {"request": request, 'ws_url' :ws_url, 'user_id' :user_id, 'callback_url' :callback_url, 'source_url' :source_url, 'time' :str(time.time())})
```

Full error is
File "/home/dev/engine/lib/python3.6/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 494, in url_path_for
raise NoMatchFound()
starlette.routing.NoMatchFound

And I am sure the error is in the last line with return templates.TemplateResponse, because I printed all the values of keys passed in this and flask are the same.
Please Help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your `homepage.html`?

Answer (score -1):

You have a path problem that's all

```
templates = Jinja2Templates(
    directory="path/to/your/templates/folder"
)
```

You do not have search for anything else it's obvious enough, just fix the path to your templates folder and it will start working smoothly.